# Value of Table Cell Referenced In Different Table Cell

Tags: excel

I have 2 tables on the same sheet. The first table "Rank" has values in column 1 (or column A) and rows 2 through 8.

I want to use the rows in the Rank table as the header row in the second table "DataTable".

I have tried using =INDEX(A2:E8,2,1) as well as structured references like
=Count(Indirect("Rank["$A$2"]")) 
and 
=Count(Indirect(Rank[[Attribute]],[A2])).

I either get an error that the formula has a mistake OR I get a value of 0 in the cell with the formula gone.

How do I get the text from the Rank table in cell A2 to be the header in column E of the DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

`Column()` will return the number of the column in your new table. You can use this to relate to the row in the first table.

Something along the lines of `=INDIRECT("RankSheet!A"&COLUMN()-3)`

The "-3" assumes that this is going in cell E1 of the new sheet, but that you want cell A2 in the Rank table, so the formula evaluation looks like:

INDIRECT("RankSheet!A" & 5-3)

INDIRECT("RankSheet!A" & 2)

INDIRECT("RankSheet!A2")

Then, as you drag this across, the increasing `COLUMN` reference will refer to an increasing row reference on the RANK table.

Comment: Thanks nwhaught, but tables are all on the same sheet. Unfortunately, that isn't working.

Comment: It should still work the same if you remove the sheet name reference.